# Ignorando uma linha de um arquivo txt

Tags: python, python-2.7

Fiz uma leitura de um arquivo .txt onde desejo separo cada palavra por virgula, ou seja, ao se encontrar um espaço antes da palavra e depois.

Mas também necessito ignorar toda a linha do txt onde se encontra o caracter ##.
Abaixo segue o código que eu estava utilizando para separa em vírgula:

```
def LeArquivo(arquivo):
linhas = arquivo.readlines()

texto = []

for line in linhas:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    texto.append(line)

return texto
```

Aqui esta o código que eu estava tentando utilizar para retirar o ##

```
def LeArquivo(arquivo):
linhas = arquivo.readlines()

texto = []

for line in linhas:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    if line.find('##') != 0:
        texto.append(line)

return texto
```

Mas ocorre um erro ao executar: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questão de ordem dos comandos, você está transformando a *string* lida em uma lista e aí fazendo a comparação mas como as listas não possuem o método `.find()` você obtém uma mensagem de erro.

Baseado na tua função uma versão passo a passo...

```py
def le_arquivo(nome_do_arquivo):
    # 1. cria a lista
    texto = []
    # 2. Abre o arquivo para leitura
    with open(nome_do_arquivo, "r") as arquivo:
        # 3. Lê cada linha do arquivo por vez
        for linha in arquivo:
            # 4. Os dois primeiros caracteres não são "##"?
            if linha[0:2] != "##":
                # 5. Então quebre a string e adicione à lista
                texto += [linha.strip().split(" ")]
    # 6. Devolve a lista
    return texto
```

Uma outra coisa você poderia até substituir o `line.find('##') != 0` por `'##' not in line` mas você estaria desnecessariamente processando uma *string* para depois não usá-la, daí fica mais eficiente você validar o caso para depois processar.

Comment: A condição também poderia ser `if(not linha.startswith('##')):...`. Boa resposta/explicação

Comment: cool! desconhecia o `"##" not in str`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Giovanni, funcionou perfeitamente aqui! Com as suas dicas até consegui fazer outras partes do código que eu precisava. Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Já agora uma versão mais compacta da versão (e menos legível) da resposta @Giovanni
(sou um bocado viciado em listas por compreensão)

```
def le(nome):
    with open(nome, "r") as arquivo:
        return[ l.split() for l in arquivo if "##" not in l ]
    return []

print(le("exemplo.txt"))
```